# Can I use variable in place of repeat count in Examine command GDB, x/10xw Address

Tags: bash, debugging, gdb, examine

In Examine command `GDB, x/10xw Address`. Can I use a variable in place of `repeat count`, i.e can I use a variable in place of 10, like `x/($var)xw Address`?

This is how my .gdbinit looks like. I need to do some calculations and use the variable ( var3 )

define print_sn_list_hex

```
            set $var1 = $mcache->elem_size
            set $var2 = $mcache->blocking_factor
             set $var3 = ($var1) * ($var2) / 4
    x/$var3xw $sess # I want to pass a variable here 



   end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Tom, `eval` command you mentioned above works perfectly. I was using older version of GDB, so it created problem inititally. its working perfectly fine now.
my new code looks like :

define print_sn_list_hex

```
        set $var1 = $mcache->elem_size
        set $var2 = $mcache->blocking_factor
         set $var3 = ($var1) * ($var2) / 4
         eval "x/%dxw %p",$var3,$sess
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can use the gdb "eval" command to get this effect, or you can write a Python script to do nearly any kind of formatting that you would desire.

Comment: Can you please show me how i can use `eval` command for the above example.

Comment: I would try something like (gdb) eval "x/%dxw $sess", $var3

Comment: Am not able to use eval inside '.gdbinit'. it says eval command not found. What do I do ?please help.

Comment: Your gdb is probably too old.